# Swagger UI can't load API docs over http/2

Tags: swagger-ui, swashbuckle, windows-server-2016, spdy

I'm trying to run Swashbuckle on an application hosted on Windows Server 2016 running HTTP/2 (aka SPDY). When I access the URL for the swagger api, I get ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR. I can access the UI page fine but it's empty because it can't retrieve the api docs.

Has anyone run into this? Any solution?

(This is with version 5.2.1.)

Comment: Outside Swashbuckle, Is your WebApi project working? can you access your endpoints and get valid responses?

Comment: It will be great if you can provide a minimal project reproducing your issue.

Comment: SPDY and HTTP/2 are actually different protocols.   Are you sure your windows server is running HTTP/2 and not SPDY?

Comment: @HelderSepu Yes, the webapi is working fine otherwise and generating the swagger file works on non-https. I can try to provide a minimal repro if you can show me a working example under https with http/2

Comment: @dzm Yes. Windows Server 2016 runs HTTP/2 but Chrome still reports the protocol error as ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

Comment: Is your API bound on :443 and :80 directly or is there a proxy in front? If so, are you terminating SSL on the proxy?

Comment: @Unglückspilz it's hosted on Azure Cloud Services. I'm not entirely sure how they handle the SSL termination. There isn't an application gateway in front of the service...